# what is the correct way to update the bias in backpropagation for a feedforward neural network?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm currently studying how to implement a neural network from scratch to know how it works, I came across this article: https://www.samsonzhang.com/2020/11/24/understanding-the-math-behind-neural-networks-by-building-one-from-scratch-no-tf-keras-just-numpy.html where he implemented a working digit classifier using MNIST dataset that has an accuracy of  83%+ almost every time I run his implementation...

I did not encounter any problem with his implementation but at some point I got curious about these part of the code when I implemented it on my own.

below is his implementation in getting the derivatives that will be used to update the weights and biases...

```
def backward_prop(Z1, A1, Z2, A2, W1, W2, X, Y):
    one_hot_Y = one_hot(Y)
    dZ2 = A2 - one_hot_Y
    dW2 = 1 / m * dZ2.dot(A1.T)
    db2 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ2)  # <-- my question is about this lines
    dZ1 = W2.T.dot(dZ2) * ReLU_deriv(Z1)
    dW1 = 1 / m * dZ1.dot(X.T)
    db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1)  # <-- my question is about this lines
    return dW1, db1, dW2, db2
```

what he is doing here is he is getting all of the sum of the resulting bias matrix as a scalar value, so I got curious is that the proper way to update the bias terms? just subtract one scalar value for all the elements of the bias matrix in a layer?

the reason why I ask that question is because when I set the line of code into `db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1,axis=0)` and `db2 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ2,axis=0)` where instead of returning a scalar value it returns a matrix and at this point when I run the model it is still working and still have a fairly high accuracy of 83%+, so I don't really know which one is correct now...

Edit: using '''axis=1,keepdims=True''' instead of '''axis=0''' seems more correct but still I'm not sure

can anyone enlighten me about this part?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's probably an error in the original code. Each bias value should be updated with the respective loss dL/db_i and not with the average over all bias terms. Hence, your solution, `db1 = 1 / m * np.sum(dZ1,axis=0)`, seems correct.

For better understanding, it would help if you comment your function/lines with each variables shape :)